# c++ std::thread on stack

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have an object with a normal constructor. The constructor has a lot of initialization to do. Much of this initialization can be performed asynchronously, so I am calling a new thread from within the constructor.

When the thread in initialized on the stack, it appears that the thread is destroyed when the constructor exits which causes a crash. This would look like so:

```
class MyObject
{
    MyObject()
    {
        // Typical initialization
        // ...

        // Time consuming initialization
        std::thread(&MyObject::Init; this); // Create new thread to call Init();

        // Crash when exit MyObject() here
    }

    void Init()
    {
         // Time consuming operations
    }
};
```

The alternative (which works) is to create the thread on the heap as such.

```
class MyObject
{
    std::thread* StartupThread;

    MyObject()
    {
        // Typical initialization
        // ...

        // Time consuming initialization
        StartupThread = new std::thread(&MyObject::Init; this); // Create new thread to call Init();

        // Crash when exit MyObject() here
    }
    ~MyObject()
    {
        StartupThread->join();
        delete StartupThread;
    }

    void Init()
    {
         // Time consuming operations
    }

};
```

---

**My Question**

Is there any harm is leaving the unjoined & undisposed thread object alive for the lifetime of the object or should I try to clean it up as soon as `Init()` finishes?

Is there a way to "automatically" dispose the thread when it finishes so it isn't left hanging around?

Essentially, can I get the thread on the stack in some way without it crashing as I described?

Comment: It shouldn't _crash_; it should detach. Also note that this is not happening at the end of your constructor, but right after the declaration, since you don't give the `std::thread` a name (this is just a temporary in an unused expression). I think you should check the lifetime of `MyObject`. Unfortunately, you did not provide a minimal testcase so it is impossible to know the true cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
class MyObject
{
    MyObject ()
    {
        f = std::async (std::launch::async, &MyObject::Init, this);
    }

private:
    void Init ();
    std::future<void> f;
};
```

This allows you to do `f.get ()` when you want to synchronize on the task. The destructor will join automatically if it is the last living copy of the object (you may want to delete the copy constructor if you don't want this behavior).

Note that you want to synchronize at some point before destruction, since if `Init` throws an exception, your destructor will.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/c11-what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits) if you want to go the `detach` route.

Comment: How is this any different than calling `join()`?

Comment: @PDizzle745: This avoids storing a (unique/shared) pointer to the thread and having to call `delete`.

Comment: @PDizzle745: Also, the future destructor will join the thread automatically (if it is the last copy), and copy construction will prolong lifetime of the task.

Comment: This is a good point. I agree then, it should be a `std::future<void>`.

Comment: That did it. Implemented this and it works like a charm. Thanks guys! And, this is easier than having the clean-up a thread handle.