# Eclipse console output for detached thread C++11

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, c++11

I have recently started exploring C++11 threads. I am using eclipse for sample programs. Output in the Eclipse console is confusing me.

When I make the detached thread wait for a second, I don't see the output from detached thread in the console.

If I don't make detached thread wait, console output seems proper.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::thread;

void hello(){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    cout << "hello from hello!" << endl;
}
int main(){

    thread(hello).detach();

    cout << "hello from main" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Console output:
**hello from main**

If hello method is as followed, output seems okay.

```
void hello(){
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    cout << "\nhello from method!" << endl;
}
```

Console output: 
**hello from main
hello from method!**

Could someone please help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: you need to wait in main thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to a detached thread when main() exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits)

Comment: Is this specifically when running in eclipse, or does it happen if you run your program from the console? I suspect eclipse's stream handling is just slightly leaky in the case that a thread prints just as the program exits.

Comment: Same thing when run from console too! (tried from cygwin terminal on windows)

Comment: @appleapple thanks! that helped.
Would the behavior  be same on visual studio?

Comment: @BharathReddy If you wait, it should be the same, but I'm not sure if you don't.