# How to correctly exit/return from main with running threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, exit

In a multithread C++ program, is it possible to use `std::exit` correctly in the middle of a parallel execution, with other running threads?

In other words, what are the preconditions to use `std::exit`?

Are third party libraries generally safe for such use?

Note: calling `std::exit` is the same as returning from an empty block in `main`:

```
int main(.....)
{ // nothing here
    {
        all the real code......
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Remark: the focus here is on the other threads; obviously returning from all functions called from `main` to be able to `return` means that all the local variables are properly destructed. That's was always true, even in pre standard C++. That isn't the point here as *it isn't a thread issue*.

Comment: Calling `exit` will forcefully terminate all other threads.

Comment: fwiw, `std::exit`: "Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called." (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)) it is not equivalent to return from main.

Comment: Joinable or detached? You still have the usual requirement that you must `join` the joinable threads.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 It's equivalent only when you are at the top level of `main` with no automatic object (local variable), or temporary object (local reference, temporary created in the same expression), obviously.

Comment: @Evg How will it stop these threads? What happens to mutexes they own?

Comment: @MSalters Good question. I don't want to restrict the discussion to either.

Comment: [What happens to a detached thread when main() exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits)

Answer (score 0):

Your premis is false. You dont need threads to break stuff with `std::exit`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit):

> Stack is not unwound: destructors of variables with automatic storage duration are not called.

Hence, for example this will not do the right thing:

```
int main() {
    auto x = some_raii_type_that_writes_to_file_on_destruction("file.ext");
    std::exit();
}
```

When you normally return from main, then...

> Returning from the main function, either by a return statement or by reaching the end of the function performs the normal function termination (calls the destructors of the variables with automatic storage durations) and then executes std::exit, passing the argument of the return statement (or ​0​ if implicit return was used) as exit_code.

That being said, `std::exit` will only perform the following steps (again [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit):

> 1) The destructors of objects with thread local storage duration that are associated with the current thread, the destructors of objects with static storage duration, and the functions registered with std::atexit are executed concurrently, [...]
>
> 2) all C streams are flushed and closed
>
> 3) files created by std::tmpfile are removed
>
> 4) control is returned to the host environment. [...]

Considering that the stack is not unwound (neither of the thread that calls `std::exit` nor others), you cannot expect some third party library to behave in a "safe" way.

Comment: Obviously resources managed by destructors may fail to be collected correctly, but some programs just count on the OS for the clean up. F.ex. on UNIX like systems, you can `unlink` temp file directly.

Comment: @curiousguy if this is obvious, why did you ask?

Comment: Why did I ask what?

Comment: @curiousguy you asked if it is safe to exit and i explained why not,  you reply that it is obvious....

Comment: Safe to exit with other threads running, lol. Not whether it's OK to not call the dtor of a ressource owning object when you want these ressources to be neatly cleaned up. Duh.

Comment: @curiousguy i was thinking about your comment for a while,  but still don't know what to reply. What exactly so you consider as "safe" (when it does not include destructors of objects getting called) ?

Comment: Safe at least means: no undefined behavior. The code must have reasonable behavior even if that means not always cleanup all resources automatically.