# Is it safe for detached thread to utilized resources owned by singleton

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a singleton like this:

```
class MySingleton{
public:
  void StartThread();
  static MySingleton& GetInstance(){
    static MySingleton st;
    return st;
  }

   // copied forbidden here
   ...
   //

private:
   // resources defined here
   ...
   //
};

void DoStuff(MySingleton*);
```

The function `StartThread()` starts a **detached** std::thread to execute `DoStuff(MySingleton*)`, which utilizes resources owned by the singleton instance.

My question is: Is it guaranteed that the thread exits before the singleton destructs(when the program exit) so that no released resources are utilzed?

Comment: Avoid this sort of thing like the plague. When you think you've got all of the cases covered, you'll just find another.

Comment: Revisit why you need a detached thread.  It will be a source of unexplained shutdown bugs unless you cleanly finish the thread before `main` exits.  That is, you might as well join the thread as the end of  `main` and not detach it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, no. According to this:

[What happens to a detached thread when main() exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits)

When the main exists the detached thread may continue, but the static variables will be destroyed. Pretty likely that you will then be causing undefined behaviour.