# C++ threads - Are threaded-function's function calls part of the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Say I have my code defined this way

```
class One
{
    //...
    //method2();
    //method3(); ...
    void method1() { method2(); method3(); }
};

int main()
{
    One obj;
    std::thread tmethod1(One::method1, obj);
    //...
    tmethod1.detach();
}
```

Will executing `obj.method1()` also put the calls to methods 2 and 3 on that separate thread?

*(I will not call method2 or method3 by themselves ever in the code).*

I do not intend to join the thread with main, I wish to keep it detached. Therefore, even if main ends, I want the separate thread and all calls in methods 2 or 3 to still run.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really correct to say that a function is on a thread.  A particular call to that function is made on a thread.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I have edited my question considering your comment.

Comment: _"even if main ends, I want the separate thread and all calls in methods 2 or 3 to still run."_ - That won't happen. When `main` ends, the program terminates. Don't detach threads.

Comment: @RichardCritten What destructor?

Comment: The compiler will implicitly call `(tmethod).std::thread::~thread()`  (It's a bit hard to describe because of moving goal posts in the question, the last edit changed the variable name)

Comment: Please be careful.  There are some surprising rules about what can or cannot happen after `main` has exited that may confound your plans to leave this thread running.  It's easiest to understand and to write correct code when you treat returning from `main` as an intention to terminate the process.  Please read answers to [What happens to a detached thread when main() exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19744250/1563833)

Comment: Don't know if this is a typo in the posting or in the original code and allowed by typical MS sloppiness, but `One::method1` is not the way to get a pointer to member function; it should be `&One::method1`.

Comment: NEVER call detach. You will only set yourself up for race condition on shutdown. With multithreading being able to shut down correctly is also very important. So the last line of main should be `tmethod1.join()` (So you stop the thread before your object goes out of scope)

Comment: Also it is more convenient to use lambda exprssions with threads so you can capture any data your thread needs to run (you get control over what to copy and what to reference). E.g. `std::thread tmethod1{ [&]{ obj.method(); });`

Comment: @PepijnKramer There are ways of safely managing detached threads (although I've always found it simpler to use `join` -- the alternatives generally involve extra condition variables).

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah I know, condition variables are my goto synchronization primitives in a lot of cases. But I've been doing multithreading for close to 30 years now and detaching is always more complicated. And somehow I see people starting with threading use it a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the calls to `method2()` and `method3` are executed in the same thread in which `method1()` was called; namely, the thread that was started on line 2 of `main`.

Once a thread is started, everything done by the thread's function occurs in that thread, except of course for operations that are specifically defined to start more new threads, or to trigger execution of code in another thread (e.g. standard library functions with an appropriate [execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Execution_policies), or [promise/future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise)).  Otherwise, code doesn't spontaneously "jump" between threads.

However...

> Therefore, even if main ends, I want the separate thread and all calls in methods 2 or 3 to still run.

That doesn't work.  There's some rather complicated discussion of the C++ standard at [What happens to a detached thread when main() exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits?rq=1).  But what happens on typical OSes in practice is that when `main` returns, all threads are immediately terminated - even if they were detached.

Threads are not the way to get a background process / daemon.  You have to use OS-specific functions, such as `fork()` on Unix-like systems.

Comment: The closing paragraph of answer may have been true on most platforms a few C++ versions ago; it no longer is.  The C++ Standard Library now provides a number of ways to schedule work to other threads without explicitly creating threads.

Comment: @BenVoigt: By "explicit" I was including any operation whose documentation says it creates threads or runs in another thread.  But I clarified.

Comment: That's definitely better.  "promise"/"future" would be another example of hidden/implicit threading

Comment: @BenVoigt Formally, there's nothing new here. Under the "as if" rule, a compiler could start all sorts of threads and distribute the work among them, as long as the externally observable behavior would be the same. (I don't know of a C++ compiler that actually does this, but I've heard of Fortran compilers that do.) And of course, since there's nothing which prevents exiting the program before the thread has terminated, there's undefined behavior, so anything goes:-).