# Why does the following program printf "thread 1 exists" twice in WSL2?

Tags: c++, concurrency, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently working with C++ multithreading on WSL2 and I've encountered something stumping. When running my program, I'm receiving duplicate printf output from a single thread. Below is the program that I'm running:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

std::atomic<int> g_Flag = 0;
std::atomic<int> cnt = 0;

void worker1(std::future<int> fut) {
    printf("this is thread 1\n");
    g_Flag = 1;
    cnt++;
    fut.get();
    printf("thread 1 exists\n");
}

void worker2(std::promise<int> prom) {
    printf("this is thread 2\n");
    g_Flag = 2;
    cnt++;
    prom.set_value(10);
    printf("thread 2 exists\n");
}

 
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
int main() {
    std::promise<int> prom;
    std::future<int> fut = prom.get_future();
    std::thread t1(worker1, std::move(fut));
    std::thread t2(worker2, std::move(prom));
    while (cnt.load() != 2) {

    }
    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
    printf("main exists\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The program output:

```
eugene@DESKTOP-P8P395D:~/tron$ ./a.out 
this is thread 1
this is thread 2
main exists
thread 2 exists
thread 1 exists
thread 1 exists
```

As you can see, it prints "thread 1 exists" twice.
Any insights on why this could be happening? I believe it may have to do with the WSL2 environment, as under normal circumstances, I would only expect each thread to print its exit message once. Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't `return` from the `main` function when you have detached threads. That will exit the process and kill all threads. On Linux, use `pthread_exit(0)` instead of `return 0`, to keep the process and the detached threads running.

Comment: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27796014/4165552) you are causing Undefined Behaviour by calling `printf` possibly after destruction of static objects.

Comment: Don't you mean "exits" instead of "exists"?

Comment: Side note: Use `detach` sparingly and prefer to `join` as detaching a thread leaves you open to many strange problems.

Comment: Whether threads keep running after the main thread exits (return from main, process terminated) is platform dependant. Linux and Windows differ in this regard for example. In general, don't leave main while threads are still running.

Answer (score 0):

Your output:

```
this is thread 1
this is thread 2
main exists
thread 2 exists
thread 1 exists
thread 1 exists
```

Before I see that *"it prints "thread 1 exists" twice."*, I see that it prints after "main exists":

- It's not recommended to use standard output (stdout) from a detached thread after the `main()` function exits.
- It’s generally a good practice to ensure all threads have completed before allowing the `main()` function to exit.

(Mitigation) To ensure `main()` exits only after workers has nothing to do / access nothing anymore, `cnt` is incremented at the very end of worker function:

```cpp
void worker1(std::future<int> fut) {
    // (The original code, minus cnt++)
    cnt++;
}

void worker2(std::promise<int> prom) {
    // (The original code, minus cnt++)
    cnt++;
}
```

--

The recommended approach involves restructuring the code:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <syncstream>


void log(const char* str)
{
     std::osyncstream ss(std::cout);
     ss << str << std::endl;
}


void worker1(std::future<int> fut) 
{
    log("this is thread 1");
    fut.get();
    log("thread 1 exists");
}


void worker2(std::promise<int> prom) 
{
    log("this is thread 2");
    prom.set_value(10);
    log("thread 2 exits");
}


int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prom;
    std::future<int> fut = prom.get_future();

    // Fire the 2 threads:
    std::thread t1(worker1, std::move(fut));
    std::thread t2(worker2, std::move(prom));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    log("main exits");
}
```

Key points:

- IMPORTANT: Replace the `while` loop ("busy wait") and `detach()` with `join()` in the `main()` to ensure that the main thread waits for all child threads to finish before exiting.
- Dilute the `#include` lines to include only what's necessary - For better practice.
- Remove unused variables - For better practice.
- Remove the unused `using namespace` directive - For better practice.
- In addition, I would also replace the `printf()` calls with `std::osyncstream`.

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/YcZ4EBFnPU)

Now, the output is:

```
this is thread 1
this is thread 2
thread 2 exits
thread 1 exits
main exits
```

--

UPDATE:

Due to your comment: *"The detach used but not join here is the requirements from test. I cannot change that."*. This solution works with `detach()`:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <syncstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>


std::mutex mtx{};
std::condition_variable cv{};
uint8_t workers_finished{ 0 }; // Counter for finished workers


void log(const char* str)
{
     std::osyncstream ss(std::cout);
     ss << str << std::endl;
}


void worker1(std::future<int> fut) 
{
    log("this is thread 1");
    fut.get();
    log("thread 1 exits");

    std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
    ++workers_finished;
    cv.notify_one(); // Signal main thread
}


void worker2(std::promise<int> prom) 
{
    log("this is thread 2");
    prom.set_value(10);
    log("thread 2 exits");

    std::lock_guard lock(mtx);
    ++workers_finished;
    cv.notify_one(); // Signal main thread
}


int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prom;
    std::future<int> fut = prom.get_future();

    // Fire the 2 threads:
    std::thread t1(worker1, std::move(fut));
    std::thread t2(worker2, std::move(prom));

    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
    
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
        while (workers_finished < 2) {
            cv.wait(lock); // Wait until notified (or spurious wakeup)
        }
    }

    log("main exits");
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/UboKp_Bpf)

Now, the output is: (The same)

```
this is thread 1
this is thread 2
thread 2 exits
thread 1 exits
main exits
```

Comment: The detach used but not join here is the requirements from test. I cannot change that. The only question is that printf thread 1 exits twice only in WSL2, but not in other env. (like in a truly baremetal with linux os)